# Why Jest use `\u221A` as test pass icon on Windows

Tags: jestjs

As [this link](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/e0b33b74b5afd738edc183858b5c34053cfc26dd/packages/jest-util/src/specialChars.ts#L14) shown, Jest uses a square root mark `\u221A` on Windows as icon, not the real check mark `\u2713`. The former will display more like a `√ ̅ ̅`  style on some font like Fira Code.

But why does Jest do that, is there some unicode issue on Windows, I can use `console.log("\u2713")` to get a correct check mark on `Chrome 96.0.4664.45`, `Windows 19044.1348`